# Determine if a value exists in an array of hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have the following:

```
array_of_hashes = [{:a=>10, :b=>20}, {:a=>11, :b=>21}, {:a=>13, :b=>23}]
```

How would I go about finding if `:a=>11` exists in `array_of_hashes`

`array_of_hashes.include?` does not seem to work

Answer (score 124, accepted):

```
array_of_hashes.any? {|h| h[:a] == 11}
```

Comment: Nice and simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

You did ask for a boolean result in the OQ, but if you really want the hash element itself do:

```
array_of_hashes.detect {  |h| h[:a] == 11 }
```

If you want the result really fast you could group the original object and then get the result with a single hash lookup:

```
t = array_of_hashes.group_by { |x| x[:a] }
t[11]
```