# ruby array includes an id

Tags: ruby

I currently want to iterate over an array of Objects (2 properties: id & name) and check if the array contains a specific Id

How would I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine if a value exists in an array of hashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514883/determine-if-a-value-exists-in-an-array-of-hashes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Enumerable#detect` is ok, but I think that `Enumerable#any?` (which returns a boolean), is strictly what you asked for:

```
xs = [{:id => 1, :name => 'a'}, {:id => 2, :name => 'b'}]
puts xs.any? {|x| x[:id] == 1} # true
puts xs.any? {|x| x[:id] == 5} # false
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [detect](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#M002176)

```
a = [{:id => 1, :name => 'a'}, {:id => 2, :name => 'b'}]
puts a.detect {|x| x[:id] == 1}
```